# Make listing look normal (ttfamily and character spacing)

Tags: listings, typography, letterspacing

`listings` seems to like protrude characters. Every time I see that I have this strange urge of killing a kitten. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\parindent0pt

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\texttt{test test test}

\begin{lstlisting}
test test test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `columns=fullflexible`

Comment: it works, but: WTF?!

Comment: `listings` was written with normal type in mind, but spaced out so to get alignment in columns. This of course is automatic if a monospaced font is used, but `columns=fullflexible` is necessary nonetheless.